# How to get two symbols “\ $“ in Swedish Apid Pro Keyboard?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I have tried all compositions such as “shift+option”`+ any other letters but there is no symbol as “\ $“. How could get it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Swedish Pro keyboard layout active in the input menu at the top right of the screen, $ is at option 4 and \ is at opton shift 7.